# What is the difference between a communication mechanism and a protocol of communication?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, game-theory, bayesian-game, mechanism-design

What is the difference between a communication mechanism and a protocol of communication in mechanism and information design. Although most papers in the literature make this distinction, it is not obvious where the difference exists.